# How to determine the signal that terminated a QProcess with Qt4 on Linux?

Tags: linux, qt4, qprocess, sigaction

I want to detect the `QProcess` I launched was terminated externally by either `SIGKILL` or `SIGTERM`. This is important in distinguishing between a crash (bug) and an external interference when I've written the process I'm launching myself.

I've tried registering watched processes through a slot connected to `QProcess::started` and setting a `SIGCHLD` handler (using [`sigaction`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html)) to capture the process status using [`waitpid`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid). The issue is that `waitpid` clears the internal kernel data structure and even if I properly chain my handler to the one on the `QProcess` implementation, the latter isn't able to get the child status as any next calls to `waitpid` for that pid fail. Setting the process state to `QProcess::ProcessState::NotRunning` through [`QProcess::setProcessState`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qprocess.html#setProcessState) avoids hanging on calls to `waitForFinished` in general, but there are corner cases which I couldn't manage to fix yet.

I was wondering if there isn't a better way to do this, other than modifying Qt's source code to store the status information somewhere.

Note: I know that crashes also terminate with a signal, which is `SIGABRT`. The main issue here is that a `SIGKILL` might tell me that the out of memory killer in Linux was the responsible for the process termination.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code, friend.

```
QProcess* pExe = new QProcess(this);
connect(pExe, SIGNAL(finished(int, QProcess::ExitStatus)), this,  SLOT(onOSRExit(int, QProcess::ExitStatus)));
pExe->setWorkingDirectory(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath());
pExe->start("some.exe");

....

void CXXXXX::onOSRExit(int exitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus exitStatus)
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't solve the issue. Under Linux I don't get the signal that killed the process on `exitCode`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution altering Qt's code under **Qt 4**, basically involves a simple modification to [`QProcessPrivate::waitForDeadChild()`](https://dreamswork.github.io/qt4/qprocess__unix_8cpp_source.html#l01309):

```cpp
if (qt_safe_waitpid(pid_t(pid), &exitStatus, WNOHANG) > 0) {
         processManager()->remove(q);
         crashed = !WIFEXITED(exitStatus);
-        exitCode = WEXITSTATUS(exitStatus);
+        exitCode = crashed ? WTERMSIG(exitStatus) : WEXITSTATUS(exitStatus);
```

The signal will then be available on `QProcess::exitCode()` after `QProcess::finished()` has been emitted.

Note: Qt5 is using Thiago Macieira's [`forkfd`](https://www.macieira.org/blog/2012/07/forkfd-part-4-proposed-solutions/), so this solution won't work.